# Android studio automatic horizontalscrollview infinite scrolling till end then repeat

Tags: java, android-studio, imageview, horizontalscrollview, autoscroll

Im using android studio , i have xml which have horizontalscrollview
Then linearlayout then multiple imageviews ..

```
<HorizontalScrollView
android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"

android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
       <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

 
</LinearLayout>
```

What i need is to make this **horizantalscrollview** to keep automatically infinite scrolling the images till the end then repeat the scrolling again and again.

what i mean by auto scrolling that the horizontalscrollview keep scrolling without using hand

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use wrap_content in layout_width?
Now, u adapt your width layout to the width of the screen, i think that if u put the value wrap_content it will solve ur problem (u have layout_height=wrap_content, but the height is "asociated" with a Vertical scroll, not with horizontal scroll):

```
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
```

I hope this help u.

Comment: the horizontalscrol view is working without am issue  , i just need instead of scroll it by hand to be scrolled automatically from beginning till the end and keep repeating

Comment: Sorry, i didn´t understand you. Look at this link: https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/7907
I think is what u want to do.

Answer (score 0):

ok Thanks for your support .. i found the solution

```
    Timer timer1 = new Timer("horizontalScrollViewTimer");
    timer1.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if (scrollingLeft) {
                        if (scroll.getScrollX() == 0) {
                            scroll.smoothScrollBy(5, 0);
                            scrollingLeft = false;
                        } else {
                            scroll.smoothScrollBy(-5, 0);
                        }
                    } else {
                        if (scroll.canScrollHorizontally(View.FOCUS_RIGHT)) {
                            scroll.smoothScrollBy(5, 0);
                        } else {
                            scroll.smoothScrollBy(-5, 0);
                            scrollingLeft = true;
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }, 1000, 50);
```